# "vtable" linker error (involving a virtual destructor with "=default") - potential bug in Clang 3.1?

Tags: c++, gcc, llvm, clang

I'm getting a linker error in my code. I have pinpointed it down to the bare essentials below.

This code gives the linker error **"vtable for Foo", referenced from: Foo::Foo()**

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
Foo::Foo() { }
```

But this code doesn't give any errors:

```
class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  virtual ~Foo() { }
};
Foo::Foo() { }
```

Why? I thought the `= default` was supposed to basically do the same thing as those empty square brackets.

**Update:** I'm using the "Apple LLVM compiler 4.1", a part of Xcode 4.5.2. Could it be a bug in this compiler? It may possibly work on the latest GCC (which Apple isn't shipping anymore though). See comments below for a discussion on compilers.

**Update 2:** As discussed below, changing the line to `virtual inline ~Foo() = default;` gets rid of this error. Doesn't this simply **have** to be a bug? Looks like the compiler doesn't recognize an inline function in this case without explicitly writing out `inline`.

Comment: Try `virtual ~Foo() noexcept = default;`. I think I had a similar problem once and gave up on `default`. Moreover, I think there's even a DR about that.

Comment: @KerrekSB Linker error is still there with `noexcept`.

Comment: This works for me with gcc 4.7.2.

Comment: @Kocka Hmm. I'm running "Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1", as a part of Xcode 4.5.2. So maybe this is just a compiler bug :(

Comment: And it works with clang 3.1 as well.

Comment: @Kocka Strange. Doing "clang --version" in my Terminal, I get "Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)" So I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Ok. Now I can reproduce it. It has to be some linker trick. It works only if the class is in the same file as main().

Comment: @Kocka I get the problem even if I put the `Foo` class into separate files (class definition into a header and the constructor implementation `Foo::Foo() { }` into a source file). And the problem occurs even if I don't include `Foo.h` in the file containing `main()`.

Comment: The problem is that implementation of virtual function cannot be inlined (in header file). I guess defaulted virtual functions have problem with that.

Answer (score 3):

[It appears to be a bug in clang which has been fixed already.](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=13424) You asked at a good time, as a new release should be coming shortly: [release candidates are already available](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-December/026295.html). Please give them a try, your example works in the i386-linux binary release, and should work in all of them.

Comment: Oh, sweet! I'll just wait for the real Clang 3.2 to appear into Xcode. Will take months probably. Until then I'll just keep that extra "inline" there.

Comment: Good job finding this out! I like how the fix is two lines of code ;)

Answer (score 2):

In the Itanium ABI, the v-table (and other RTTI information) is emitted for the translation unit containing the definition of the first virtual method not defined inline in the class, or if there are only virtual methods defined inline, for every translation unit that includes the class. It's then up to the linker to merge the redundant symbols.

It is possible that by specifying `= default`, Clang does not realize that you have **defined** the `virtual` method inline in the class and that each and every TU that includes your file should define the v-table and RTTI info, and instead is waiting for the definition to appear somewhere.

May I suggest putting the definition *outside* the class ? => `Foo::~Foo() = default;`

Comment: It did indeed work to put `Foo::~Foo() = default;` into the implementation file (i.e. not the header file where the class definition is). However, interestingly, it also worked to add `inline` to the line within the class itself: `virtual inline ~Foo() = default;` Isn't this a guaranteed bug? Seems like it's not recognizing the inline, even though it is inline.

Comment: @DennisRitchie: It definitely sounds like a bug. I am not surprised since `= default` is a new construct. Like all new stuff, it takes time to flush out bugs.

Comment: I just found out that the linker error goes away if there simply exists a subclass that derives from `Foo` (even if the subclass is empty). Do you have any technical explanations for why this would make the compiler any happier?

Comment: @DennisRitchie: no :x The problem with bugs is that they are flimsy.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with g++ 4.7.2. But I have the same problem as you with clang 3.1.

I have 3 files.

Foo.h:

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

class Foo {
public:
  Foo();
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};

#endif // FOO_H
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo() { }
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

But if it is like this, it works with clang as well:

Foo.cpp is empty.

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std;

Foo::Foo() { }

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    return 0;
}
```

So I guess clang has bug during generating the objectfile.